# Trying to get appended button to display block hidden element within a set and close all others

Tags: jquery, html

I have three field sets that appear one at a time once a continue button on the previous set is clicked. I am also appending another edit button on the recently closed fieldset parent. The purpose of the edit button is to allow someone to open that particular fieldset.

The problem I have is when the edit button is clicked it does not open the fieldset within that set. If i just use the following code without the rest of the code it works just fine, so I am not sure why it does not work with the rest of it:

```
    $('.edit').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.ap_sectionblock').find("fieldset").toggle();
});
```

Here is the code that i am using:

http://jsfiddle.net/joseph_a_garcia/eFf9d/

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use event delegation, your edit button is created dynamically and appended to DOM. But your click events are bound on Document ready when they dont exist yet. So attach the event to the document head or any other container that exist in DOM at any point in time, SO that the event gets delegated to the edit button created in the future from the specified container.

```
$('.ap_private_party_form').on('click', '.edit', function(){
    $(this).closest('.ap_sectionblock').find("fieldset").show();
});
```

For 1.7+ version of jquery use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for older versions use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

#### Update for your continuation issue

```
$('.close-and-show-next').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('fieldset').hide();
    var $block = $this.closest(".ap_sectionblock");
    $block.find('.ap_sectionheader').append('<span><input type="button" class="edit" value="Edit"></span>');
    $block.next(".ap_sectionblock").find("fieldset").show();
    //return false;
});


$('.ap_private_party_form').on('click', '.edit', function () {
    $('.ap_sectionblock').find('fieldset:visible').hide(); // Just hide the fieldSets that are visible on click of edit of any so that only one is shown at a time.
    $(this).closest('.ap_sectionblock').find("fieldset").show(); // show this ones fieldset
    $(this).remove(); // remove the edit button as you don't need it any more on the edit page.
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wTQuq/)

Comment: @PSL.. Also the OP's code appends multiple `edit` buttons as he seems to be appending multiple times.. Need to add a check for that

Comment: Thanks PSL, it works except once I click edit button and then click the continue button within that set the edit button is duplicated. How do I keep that from happening?

Comment: Here the fiddle without adding an edit button everytime : http://jsfiddle.net/eFf9d/11/. Added this condition `if(!$this.parent().parent().find('.ap_sectionheader').find('.edit').length)$this.parent().parent().find('.ap_sectionheader').append('<span><input type="button" class="edit" value="Edit"></span>');` which could be optimised by the way.

Comment: @JosephGarcia Oh god its a sea of html in there in fiddle.. What exactly that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @PSL Yea sorry about that. I should have simplified it some. But between you and ericdc I think I have something to work with.

Comment: I'm trying to allow a user to go through multiple form fields without actually seeing all fields at the same time. By allowing them to go through one set and continuing on to the next set it makes for a better user experience. The caveat to this particular flow is that users need to be able to go back and edit fields if need be. I'm essentially trying to create an accordion. Hopefully that makes sense. Thanks for the assist again.

Comment: Thanks to Karl Andre as well!

Comment: Updated the answer with what you are looking for.

Comment: @JosephGarcia ok cool. Pleas do remember to mark as answer, for more that what you asked for :)

Answer (score 0):

The edit item was created after the javascript binding. The jquery .on method will solve this by attaching the event to a parent element that is on the page when it originally loaded.

```
$('.ap_sectionblock').on('click', '.edit',function(){
    $(this).closest('.ap_sectionblock').find("fieldset").show();
});
```

It is best to bind the "on" to the nearest non changing element and not the document root since jquery will have to bubble this event all the way up the DOM. It makes things faster on complex documents.

http://jsfiddle.net/eFf9d/8/